# UICollectionView cellForItemAt not called second time

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a project were you login and after that images are loaded from the web into a collectionView. I set number of sections to 1 and the first time i login everything is displayed properly.
I can see the following order:

- numberOfSection      (giving 1 here)
- numberOfItemsInSection 0
- insetForSectionAt

then i have an event when my images are downloaded and i call following code didFinishDownloadingTo

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    let url=(downloadTask.currentRequest?.url)?.pathComponents


    let urlId = (url!.last)!
    let offerIndex = self.downloadIndex[urlId]
    let imageData=try? Data(contentsOf: location)

    if imageData != nil && offerIndex != nil && self.offers[offerIndex!] != nil /* && offerIndex! < self.offers.count */ {
        self.stopAutoScrolling()

        //Sending to background thread since we see in profile that this takes time and hanging main thread
        DispatchQueue.global(priority: DispatchQueue.GlobalQueuePriority.default).async(execute: {
            self.downloadCache[urlId] = imageData
            self.offers[offerIndex!]!.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            self.updateCache()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.setupDataForCollectionView()
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                self.startAutoScrolling()
            }

        })

    }

}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return self.view.frame.size
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: -64, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("section num \(section)")

    return carousel.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! EventOfferCell

    //LoggingManager.sharedInstance.logInfo("Carousel count %i indexPath %i", carousel.count,indexPath.row)
    if let offer = offerForIndexPath(indexPath) {
        if let offerImage = offer.image {
            cell.imageView.image = offerImage
            cell.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            cell.titleLabel.isHidden = true
        }
        else {
            cell.titleLabel.text = offer.title
        }
    }

    return cell
}

func setupDataForCollectionView() {
    carousel.removeAll()
    for (_, offer) in self.offers {
        carousel.append(offer)
    }
    if carousel.count > 1 {
        let firstOffer = carousel.first
        let lastOffer = carousel.last

        carousel.append(firstOffer!)
        carousel.insert(lastOffer!, at: 0)
    }
}
```

After the reloadData i get the following scenario:

- numberOfSection      (giving 1 here)
- numberOfItemsInSection 4
- sizeForItemAt
- cellForItemAt is called and I set my images that I want to scroll between

Though **second time** after I logout and the collection view is loaded i get the same scenario though after reloadData when the images are downloaded nothing is happening, no numberOfSection call nothing.
I have really tried many different solutions but nothing works.
Since cellForItemAt and sizeForItemAt is not called I get no images displayed the second time i login

I have tried to set numberOfItemsInSection statically to 2 and provide two images statically and that is working since then  sizeForItemAt is called etc

My dataSource and delegate are set in the storyboard to the correct Controller

I am really stuck at this problem so all help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved it was my downloadTask that cached my images second round and the reloadData was not called in downloadtask callback